# Joining tables on different databases, while bindingValues

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to update a table with info from boundValues. Except for the city_id. I need to use the city from the boundValue to get its associated city_id from `x`

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare(
                "
                UPDATE x_addresses
                INNER JOIN x ON x = x...
                SET
                    customer_id = :userId,
                    first_name = :firstname,
                    last_name = :lastname,
                    state = :state,
                    company_name = :company,
                    street1 = :street1,
                    street2 = :street2,
                    postal = :postalCode,
                    country = :country,
                    city = :city,
                    city_id = x,
                    region = :region,
                WHERE customer_id = $id
            "
            );
```

Comment: by doing this `WHERE customer_id = $id`, the `bindValue()` is useless

Comment: also are you 100% sure your update syntax is correct?

Comment: I probably should just do `WHERE customer_id = :userId` right? It's the same value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant access table column value, unless you have not selected it. In here you can just have update to make sure that this label exists, but you cant select value, you have to do different database query for that.

e.g.

```
select dbCore.locations_zones_cities.city_id from table where x
update x
```